# which ports to use when setting up proxy server

Tags: windows, server, proxy, ip

I am using VPS and setting different proxies on that VPS.

Which ports are safest to use for proxies? (considering that I want to stay anonymous when using proxy, which means that I do not want anyone to detect that I am using a proxy)

So far I have used 443 and 2171 (I dont know why, I have found somewhere that these are good for proxies). 
But I am going to set up maybe 5 more proxies on that VPS, so which ports should I use for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

443 port is usually used for SSL related stuff. Its a well known port for attack. To stay anonymous use 4 or 5 digit ports like 5*** or 9*** those are usually not taken by any program and always free to allocate.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
So, for anonymity reasons it does not really matter which ports to use, but for security reasons it is recommended to use ports which consist of 4 or 5 digits?